# Kotlin eval() support

Tags: kotlin, eval

Как запустить код динамически вроде функции eval() в Python ?

```
fun mix(amount : Int){
    val funcs  = arrayOf("transponding()" , "swapRowsSmall()", 
            "swapRowsArea()","swapColumnArea()","swapColumnsSmall()")

    for (i in 0..amount){
        eval(funcs[Random().nextInt( (funcs.size - 0) + 0)])
    }
}
```

Как можно переписать этот код, чтобы он заработал ?

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так, с использованием лямбд:

```
fun mix(amount : Int){
    val funcs:Array<()->Unit>  = arrayOf({transponding()} , {swapRowsSmall()}, 
            {swapRowsArea()},{swapColumnArea()},{swapColumnsSmall()})

    for (i in 0..amount){
        funcs[Random().nextInt(funcs.size - 1)]()
    }
}
```

Comment: функции eval() нету в Kotlin , нужно использовать что-то другое и я не знаю что

Comment: @Vlad поправил ответ. Конечно `eval` там не нужен

Comment: Спасибо ! Довольно интересное решение. В Kotlin in Action не встречал подобной записи  Array<()->Unit>. Может просто не дочитал =)

Comment: @Vlad `()->Unit` - означает лямбду, которая не принимает параметров `()` и ничего не возвращает `Unit`. Лямбда в Kotlin является совершенно обычным типом, который можно передавать, возвращать и складывать в коллекции